# AHK Anagram solver

Tags: script, autohotkey

I'm trying to make a "real time" anagram solver, but the only way I can think of is gonna take AGES to make.

for example with the word tree:

```
::reet::tree
::eret::tree
::eert::tree
::teer::tree
::rtee::tree
```

and so on...
It works, but it would take me ages to make atleast 100 words. Is there a easier way to make this with a dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

Completely off topic for SU.

However, you will *never* be able to accomplish this.

There are 1,025,109 words in the English language and it is still growing.

The *average* length of a word in the English language is 5.1 characters.  That is 5! (factorial), or 120 combinations of letters.

The longest word in a major dictionary is [Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis), which is 45 characters in length.  There are 45! (factorial) possible combinations of letters.  That is 1.1962222086548E56 combinations of letters.  That is 119,622,220,865,480,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 possible combinations of characters that can be made up of those letters.

Not to mention some words combinations will have multiple correct answers.  Take ha/ah, big/gib, and/nad, male/lame/alme etc.

Good luck.